# How can I set the inbuilt payment method based on store id

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.8, magento-1.5, magento-1.6

I want to show the Magento existing inbuilt payment method based on store Id.I have two store and want to show Cash on delivery and pay pal on one store and do not want these payment method on another store.Please help

Answer (score 1):

When deciding which payment methods to show Magento will issue an event. You can register observer for that event and filter payment list by store ID. Here is how to do it.

Create new module for the observer. Register observer in your config.xml:

```
<confg>
...
<frontend>
...
    <events>
        <payment_method_is_active>
            <observers>
                <company_module>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Company_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>frontendPaymentMethods</method>
                </company_module>
            </observers>
        </payment_method_is_active>
    </events>
</frontend>
</config>
```

And then create model for the observer class Model/Observer.php with frontendPaymentMethods function:

```
<?php
class Company_Module_Model_Observer {
  public function frontendPaymentMethods($observer) {
    $quote = $observer->getData('quote');
    $result = $observer->getData('result');
    $method = $observer->getData('method_instance');

    if($method->getCode() == 'banktransfer' && Mage::app()->getStore() == 5) {
        $result->isAvailable = false;
    }
} 
}
```

This will disable banktransfer payment method for store with id 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Magento configuration under System > Configuration. Choose one of the stores in the dropdown list at the top left corner of the configuration page. And disable Cash on delivery and paypal payment methods. This will be a store specific configuration, that means these payment methods will be disabled only in that store and available in other.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/overview-how-multiple-websites-stores-work/

Comment: we can't do this .there is no option in payment method for enabling or disabling based on particular store choosen from drop down.we can set it only for default store.

Comment: You are right, it does not work for standard magento payment methods. Works on our custom methods though. Ok, there is another way we did when we needed to enable payment methods for backend only. It involves creating observer I'll post it as another answer.